# Makerbot layer thickness

Tags: replicating-printers

I'm using PETG, the thickness of the filament is 1.75mm, in MakerBot there is a setting for "Layer Height", the default is 0.1mm, I've had lots of messed up prints with this material and I'm thinking it could be this setting that needs adjustment.

What layer thickness should be used?

Found this:  http://forum.makergear.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike PLA, PETG does not like to be "squidged" down, it likes to be *laid* down. If you use too small a layer height, there is the danger of the filament sticking to the nozzle, rather than the bed (or filament already laid down). Try using a larger layer height -- between 0.2mm and 0.3mm, if you have a 0.4mm nozzle.

Comment: Thank you, I've set the Layer Height to 0.25 and now its printing fine, world of difference.

Comment: @SPlatten There is no good reason for a default layer height of 0.1mm, although some printer manufacturers use it. A layer height of 0.2mm should be fine for most applications.